# SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database

Tags: sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Pertaining to the video by Firebase below, I have the following question- I have not received a response on YouTube yet, and was wondering if anyone here knows of a possible solution.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs

**In General** I want to be able to know how to query data for selected items, and not all data in a set.

**Specific Question**: Instead of pulling all entries in a child ref, how can we select specific entries (key & value) from the data in Firebase? I'm having bad luck nesting with orderByChild() & I believe would need the on value listener event he began to mention.

For Example (#2): SELECT Name from Users WHERE email = "alice@email.com" instead of SELECT * from Users WHERE email = "alice@email.com"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919532/fetch-particular-fields-from-firebase-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109485/retrieving-all-the-data-from-firebase-excluding-some-fields, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596678/nosql-data-structure-to-select-subset-of-fields-with-firebase-and-query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079674/read-only-certain-fields-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the client SDKs.  When you receive a node, you will get all of its children every time.

If you need to limit the amount of data from a query, you will have to split the parent node into separate nodes that contain only the data for a desired query.  Sometimes people duplicate data into different nodes just to create special queryable nodes for a specific purpose.  This is fairly common to do with NoSQL type databases, and it's called data denormalization.